# Crashplan DSCP QoS setting on MacOS does not work?

Tags: networking, macos, qos, crashplan, crashplan-central

I'm using Crashplan on a Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan.

Under network settings, if I change the DSCP decimal value to '10' and restart the service, I see no change in the outgoing traffic.

It seems that this feature is broken on [Windows](http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2012/06/07/crashplan-upload-traffic-with-dscp-tos-and-qos-on-windows-7/), Linux ([at least on a Synology NAS](http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2015/10/06/crashplan-on-synology-diskstation-successfully-setting-qos-dscp-values-to-de-prioritize-upload-traffic/)) and also here again on MacOS.

Is there a way to enable DSCP tagging on Crashplan traffic on MacOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The fix

There is now a support article that covers this on the Crashplan site citing a fix for both Windows and Mac running Crashplan 4.7+ or 5.3+

https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/TCP_Packet_QoS_Settings_Not_Applied_To_The_CrashPlan_App

You need to add the follow line to /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist

```
Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Within the format of that config file, this is added as an array item,  literally as (note leading hyphen) `<string>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true</string>`

My config file looked like this:

[image]

### File permissions

File permissions may need to be changed to allow edit on that file (get info > permissions), then reverted again. If you accidentally change ownership as I did, Crashplan will fail to start. You can restore 'system' (root) ownership from the terminal with `sudo chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.crashplan.engine.plist`

### Checking DSCP with TCPDUMP

From the terminal you can check DSCP tagging of port 443 traffic over 5 seconds with `tcpdump -i en0 tcp dst port 443 -c 5 -vvv`

This then showed that with a configured DSCP decimal setting of '10', I see the equivalent ToS Hex of 0x28 :)

[image]